# Google Drive API file download status 0

Tags: download, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive javascript api V2 to download files.  This has been working just fine for some time but today it is failing, returning status 0 with a blank response text.  Looking at the network calls, I can see that I am authenticating successfully and navigating to the correct folders and retrieving a list of files but it will no longer download those files.

Looking deeper, I can see the initial response to each file download returns a status 307 (temporary redirect) and a redirect location in the response header.  The browser automatically processes the location with a new request header but I do not get a response with any content, rather just an error with the status 0.

Is there a specific reason for the status 307 and is there a special way in which they should be handled?

This is the code used to download:

```js
    // Download file contents
    downloadFile: function ( fileItem, callback ) {
        var me = this,
            accessToken,
            xhr;

        if ( fileItem.downloadUrl ) {
            accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onerror = function () {
                callback( { error: { code: xhr.status, message: xhr.statusText } } );
            };
            xhr.open( 'GET', fileItem.downloadUrl, true );
            xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken );
            xhr.overrideMimeType( "application/json" );
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
                if ( xhr.readyState === DONE ) {
                    if ( xhr.status === 200 ) {
                        callback( xhr.responseText );
                    } else {
                        callback( { error: { code: xhr.status, message: xhr.statusText } } );
                    };
                };
            };
            xhr.send();
        } else {
            callback( { error: { code: "?", message: "Downloaded URL not specified" } } );
        };
    },
```

Comment: I can't see where exactly you are using the Drive API. I mean, how are you calling it?

Comment: The parameter ‘fileItem’ is derived from the gapi.client.drive.files.list command where the item ‘downloadUrl’ was specified and it is that URL I am using for the download.

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this question despite not getting a resolution.  I have updated my code to use v3 of the Google Drive api and have got it working using that.

Strangely, if I used the HTTP request Url `'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<fileId>'` it still didn't work but if I used the command:

```
gapi.client.drive.files.get( {
        'fileId': fileItem.id,
        'alt': 'media',
        'mimeType': fileItem.mimeType
    });
```

it works okay.

Not sure what Google have done as my previous code had been working for a couple of years without any change my end but at least I am back up and running again.